# How to break an integer array into N parts in all possible combination?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to break an array into N parts, with a condition that all parts gets at least 1 number.

Example: If an array [5, 10, 10, 30] is broken into 2 (N=2) parts, then all possible part combination will be:

- combination #1 : *5 | 10, 10, 30*.
- combination #2 : *5, 10 | 10, 30*.
- combination #3 : *5, 10, 10 | 30*

My code so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 5, 10, 10, 30 };
        int maxElement = 3;
        int count = 1;
        while (count <= maxElement) {
            printCombinations(count, a);
            count++;
        }

    }

    public static void printCombinations(int count, int[] a) {
        System.out.println("start printing");
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {

            System.out.println(a[index]);
        }
        System.out.println("----");
        for (int index = count; index < a.length; index++) {

            System.out.println(a[index]);
        }
        System.out.println("end printing");
    }
```

It is printing the combinations as expected. But I am unable to figure out how to generalize this for N. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: for `[5, 10, 10, 30]` if `N=3` what will be the combination?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod a combination with n=2 for the second part of a classic combination n=2

Comment: The parts are always in order? E.g. `5, 30 | 10, 10` is not a valid 4th solution for N=2?

Comment: Why does `N=2` outline 3 different combinations, if the array should be "broken" into 2 equal parts?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod: 5| 10 |10,30 ; 5,10| 10 |30 ; and 5| 10,10 |30.

Comment: Ah, never mind, i see.... these are "options", not the result.

Comment: @MaxVollmer: No. I don't need to change the array element order.

Comment: @dognose OP never said anything about 2 equal parts. OP wants all possible combinations of N parts, for any N.

Comment: To me this sounds almost more like a math than a pure programming question. It might be better to ask on math.exchange for figuring out the algorithm, and then, if need be, here for help how to implement the algorithm. But other people upvoted, so I might be mistaken. I mean, it is an intriguing and challenging problem for sure.

Comment: @MaxVollmer: thanks Max. I might ask there later. To add to the answer to your previous question: `5, 30 | 10, 10` can be a valid combination as well. My idea was to permute the original array and feed the permutations into this program to get all the part combinations.

Comment: @user3274247   The technical term is partitioning, for example for array of size `5` when `N=3` that means we are partitioning `5` with exactly 3 addends?

Comment: There's a similar question on math.stackexchange: [Number of ways to write n as a sum of k nonnegative integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers). In your case `n` is the array length and `k` is the number of partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert array to ArrayList to make it easier to work on the dataset.

I used recursion to separate the left part of the array and recursively compute the right part.

Might not be the best code, but it works. I'll try to improve the variable names if I get time.

**Explaining the use of `List<List<List<Integer>>>`**:-

Suppose the input is

```
a = { 5, 10, 10, 30 }
n = 2
```

The combinations will be:-

```
combination #1: 5 | 10, 10, 30
combination #2: 5, 10 | 10, 30
combination #3: 5, 10, 10 | 30
```

To store these 3 combinations, the outermost `List<>` is used.

The second `List<>` stores sections within each combination. So combination #1 will have 2 sections, [5] and [10, 10, 30].

The inner-most `List<Integer>` is used to store the integers within each section. So section #2 in combination #1 will have a list of 10, 10, 30.

**Solution**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] a = {5, 10, 10, 30};
    final List<List<List<Integer>>> combinations = getCombinations(2, Arrays.asList(a));
    for (List<List<Integer>> combination : combinations)
        System.out.println(combination);
}

public static List<List<List<Integer>>> getCombinations(int n, List<Integer> a) {
    if (n == 1) {
        List<List<List<Integer>>> singleLine = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> singleSection = new ArrayList<>();
        singleSection.add(a);
        singleLine.add(singleSection);
        return singleLine;
    }
    List<List<List<Integer>>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    if (n > a.size()) return res;
    if (n == a.size()) {
        List<List<Integer>> sections = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer e : a) {
            List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(e);
            sections.add(l);
        }
        List<List<List<Integer>>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add(sections);
        return lines;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= a.size() - n + 1; i++) {
        List<List<Integer>> left = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> leftElements = new ArrayList<>();
        left.add(leftElements);
        leftElements.addAll(a.subList(0, i));
        List<List<List<Integer>>> subResult = getCombinations(n - 1, a.subList(i, a.size()));
        for (List<List<Integer>> r : subResult) {
            res.add(Stream.concat(left.stream(), r.stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Input 1**

```
a = {5, 10, 10, 30}
n = 2
```

**Output 1**

```
[[5], [10, 10, 30]]
[[5, 10], [10, 30]]
[[5, 10, 10], [30]]
```

**Input 2**

```
a = {5, 10, 10, 30}
n = 3
```

**Output 2**

```
[[5], [10], [10, 30]]
[[5], [10, 10], [30]]
[[5, 10], [10], [30]]
```

**Input 3**

```
a = {5, 10, 10, 30, 40}
n = 3
```

**Output 3**

```
[[5], [10], [10, 30, 40]]
[[5], [10, 10], [30, 40]]
[[5], [10, 10, 30], [40]]
[[5, 10], [10], [30, 40]]
[[5, 10], [10, 30], [40]]
[[5, 10, 10], [30], [40]]
```